# PHP adding to array with substr

Tags: php, arrays

I've got a bit of weird problem.
I have data sent via post:

```
Array
(
    [test_amount_9] => 9
    [sell_cost_9] => 102.41
    [cost_quote_9] => 2253.02
    [test_amount_10] => 10
    [sell_cost_10] => 13.68
    [cost_quote_10] => 451.44
    [q] => /portal/orders/create-commerical-offer
)
```

Then I have a foreach, which loops through each item and tests for the first 4 characters with substr and if so, add it to the array.

```
$items = array();
        foreach($input as $item => $key) {
            // if first 4 chars are sell, remove sell_cost_ and save the ID
            if(substr($item, 0, 4) == 'sell') {
                $id = str_replace(substr($item, 0, 10), '', $item);
                $cost = $key;

                $items[$id] = array(
                    'id' => $id,
                    'sell_cost' => $cost
                );

                // if first 4 chars are cost, add to array
            } elseif(substr($item, 0, 4) == 'cost') {
                $id = str_replace(substr($item, 0, 11), '', $item);
                $items[$id]['price_per_case'] = $key;

                // add amount to array
            } elseif(substr($item, 0, 4) == 'test') {
                $id = str_replace(substr($item, 0, 12), '', $item);
                $items[$id]['amount'] = 'sdadassda';
                //$items[$id]['amount'] = $key;
                //$items['shouldbe'][] = array($item => $key);
            } else {
                $items['unknown'][] = array($item => $key);
            }
        }
```

The first two substr works, and I end up with this result.

```
Array
(
    [9] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [sell_cost] => 102.41
            [price_per_case] => 2253.02
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [sell_cost] => 13.68
            [price_per_case] => 451.44
        )

    [unknown] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [q] => /portal/orders/create-commerical-offer
                )

        )

)
```

I have no idea where the amount is going. I've tried changing the name (hence the prefix test_) and the data just seems to disappear. 
Thanks.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. You have 'q' which goes into the ELSE clause and it does what it is supposed to do ?

Comment: The arrays are missing the amount, which currently should be $items[$id]['amount'] = 'sdadassda';
Also, 'q' is added by Laravel.

Comment: But you dont have any input data that would hit the ifelse clause with amount? None of your array keys start with 'test'?

Comment: "test_amount_9" and "test_amount_10" do. They are not added into the array and they are not added into the "unknown" array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $items array is overwritten when you you get to cost (and you handle amount before resetting the array in the code that happens with cost)

This WILL work (I put amount at the end instead of in the beginning).

```
$input = Array
(
'sell_cost_9' => 102.41,
'cost_quote_9' => 2253.02,
'test_amount_9' => 9,
'sell_cost_10' => 13.68,
'cost_quote_10' => 451.44,
'test_amount_10' => 10,
'q' => '/portal/orders/create-commerical-offer'
);
```

EDIT: this is your code in 'cost' that resets the array (after amount is added, so amount is removed here):

```
$items[$id] = array(
  'id' => $id,
  'sell_cost' => $cost
);
```

Comment: So simple. I've chucked an isset statement in each step to make sure it isn't overwritten. It is always the simplest solution, eh? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
It's very straight $items array is overwritten, to avoid this Just set $items as multidimensional ARRAY, it won't overwrite.

$input =Array
(
    'test_amount_9' => 9,
    'sell_cost_9' => 102.41,
    'cost_quote_9' => 2253.02,
    'test_amount_10' => 10,
    'sell_cost_10' => 13.68,
    'cost_quote_10' => 451.44,
    'q' => '/portal/orders/create-commerical-offer'
);
$items = array();
        foreach($input as $item => $key) {
            // if first 4 chars are sell, remove sell_cost_ and save the ID
            if(substr($item, 0, 4) == 'sell') {
                $id = str_replace(substr($item, 0, 10), '', $item);
                $cost = $key;

                $items[][$id] = array(
                    'id' => $id,
                    'sell_cost' => $cost
                );

                // if first 4 chars are cost, add to array
            } elseif(substr($item, 0, 4) == 'cost') {
                $id = str_replace(substr($item, 0, 11), '', $item);
                $items[][$id]['price_per_case'] = $key;

                // add amount to array
            } elseif(substr($item, 0, 4) == 'test') {
                $id = str_replace(substr($item, 0, 12), '', $item);
                $items[][$id]['amount'] = 'sdadassda';
                //$items[][$id]['amount'] = $key;
                //$items[]['shouldbe'][] = array($item => $key);
            } else {
                $items[]['unknown'][] = array($item => $key);
            }
        }




**Output**

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [9] => Array
                (
                    [amount] => sdadassda
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [9] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 9
                    [sell_cost] => 102.41
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [9] => Array
                (
                    [price_per_case] => 2253.02
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [10] => Array
                (
                    [amount] => sdadassda
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [10] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 10
                    [sell_cost] => 13.68
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [10] => Array
                (
                    [price_per_case] => 451.44
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [unknown] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [q] => /portal/orders/create-commerical-offer
                        )

                )

        )

)


Hope It Hepls!!

If you want to format it according to you just do a foreach()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the key of the array item into an array, like $itemArr = explode('_', $itemKey), you would have a better way to deal with each of them. 
For instance, the id would be $id = $itemArr[count($itemArr)-1], and instead of compare like this: substr($item, 0, 4) == 'cost', you could do like this: $itemArr[0] == 'cost', without the limitation of knowing the length of $item.

```
        $items = array();
        foreach ($input as $item => $key) {
            $itemArr = explode('_', $item);
            $id = $itemArr[count($itemArr)-1];
            switch ($itemArr[0]) {
            case 'sell':
                $items[$id] = array(
                     'id' => $id,
                     'sell_cost' => $key,
                );
            break;
            case 'cost':
                $items[$id] = array(
                     'id' => $id,
                     'price_per_case' => $key,
                );
            break;
            case 'test':
                $items[$id] = array(
                     'id' => $id,
                     'amount' => $key,
                );
            break;
            default:
                $items['unknown'] = array(
                     $item => $key,
                );
            break;
            }
        }
```

Realize that if you have more than one unknown item, you will have only the last one.